# XPath to pick an element based on the text in parent or any of its child

Tags: html, xpath

Is there a way to pick an element if that element or any one of the child has a particular text?

For example, Here are two examples:

Example 1:

```
<div title='Title1'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  "Tag 1"
</div>
```

Example 2:

```
<div title='Title2'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <span>Tag 1<span>
</div>
```

I want to pick tag div regardless if the text is inside the span or not.

But the below XPath picks the tag span for the second case.

```
//*[(contains(text(), 'Tag 1'))]
```

Is there any better XPath to pick the div based on the text inside the parent or any of the child?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any better XPath to pick the div based on the text inside the parent or any of the child?

Use `.`, not `text()`.

```
//*[contains(., 'Tag 1')]
```

`text()` does not give you the element's "text".

It gives you a list (!) of *text nodes* that are direct children of the current context node. When the context node is `<div>` in example #2, that list would be three text nodes containing only whitespace. I've highlighted them with brackets:

```
<div title='Title2'>[
  ]<input type='checkbox' />[
  ]<span>Tag 1<span>[
]</div>
```

`'Tag 1'` is a child of `<span>`, not of `<div>`.

Now, `contains()` does not accept node lists. If you give it a node list, it will only consider the *string value* of the very first node in that list. The string value of a node is the concatenation of all text nodes it contains, not just direct children.

`.` refers to the context node. In example #2 that's the `<div>` itself. `contains()` again converts it to string, but this time, that string actually contains `Tag 1`. Another way to write this is:

```
//*[contains(string(.), 'Tag 1')]
```

That's what you thought `text()` would do.

Now `//*` is recursive, this means the `<div>` will be selected, the `<span>` and all the `<div>` ancestors, too, because they all contain `Tag 1` at some point.

Use something more specific than `//*` to fix this.